# Image Position slide in menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Happy Easter All I am trying to get a image link open and close to stay beside a slide push menu

the menu i am using is here its the very first one

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

the open in close i want to move with the menu like here

https://www.callofduty.com/blackops3/ce

if you look at the menu icon it moves with the menu... I have tried position new div nothing has worked.

```
<nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
            <h3>Menu</h3>            
            <a href="#">Celery seakale</a>
            <a href="#">Dulse daikon</a>
            <a href="#">Zucchini garlic</a>
            <a href="#">Catsear azuki bean</a>
            <a href="#">Dandelion bunya</a>
            <a href="#">Rutabaga</a>
  </nav>



<button id="showLeft" class="btn2"><img src="content/media/icon-bar.jpg" alt="Menu"></button>


/* General Demo Style */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.svg#fontawesome') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body, html { font-size: 100%;   padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* Reset */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #47a3da;

}

a {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.main,
.container > header {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.875em 3.125em 1.875em;
}

.container > header {
    padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
}

.container > header h1 {
    font-size: 2.125em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container > header span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}

.container > header nav {
    float: right;
}

.container > header nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: transparent;
    margin: 0 0.1em;
    border: 4px solid #47a3da;
    text-indent: -8000px;
}

.container > header nav a:after {
    content: attr(data-info);
    color: #47a3da;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600%;
    top: 120%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.container > header nav a:hover {
    background: #47a3da;
}

.main > section {
    max-width: 260px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main > section h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ccc;
}

.main > section button {
    border: none;
    background: #47a3da;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.main > section button:hover {
    background: #258ecd;
}

.main > section button.active {
    background: #0d77b6;
}

.main > section button.disabled {
    background: #aaa;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.icon-drop:before, 
.icon-arrow-left:before {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #47a3da;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-indent: 8000px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
}

.icon-drop:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.icon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\f060";
}






/* General styles for all menus */
.cbp-spmenu {
    background-image:url(../../media/opacityBG.png);
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;   
}

.cbp-spmenu h3 {
    color: #afdefa;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #0d77b6;
}

.cbp-spmenu a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:hover {
    background: #258ecd;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:active {
    background: #afdefa;
    color: #47a3da;
}

/* Orientation-dependent styles for the content of the menu */

.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cbp-spmenu-vertical a {
    padding: 1em;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal h3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.8em;
    border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}

/* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */

.cbp-spmenu-left {
    left: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right {
    right: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-left.cbp-spmenu-open {
    left: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right.cbp-spmenu-open {
    right: 0px;
}

/* Horizontal menu that slides from the top or bottom */

.cbp-spmenu-top {
    top: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom {
    bottom: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-top.cbp-spmenu-open {
    top: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open {
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Push classes applied to the body */

.cbp-spmenu-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
    left: 240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
    left: -240px;
}

/* Transitions */

.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Example media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 55.1875em){

    .cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
        font-size: 75%;
        height: 110px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-top {
        top: -110px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-bottom {
        bottom: -110px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-height: 26.375em){

    .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
        font-size: 90%;
        width: 190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-left,
    .cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
        left: -190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-right {
        right: -190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
        left: 190px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to post some code!

Comment: Some codes or fiddle would help figuring what's wrong

Comment: can you send me your html, css, jS code so we can help you.

Comment: Just add image(open/close) as absolute position

Comment: Silambarasan I tried no luck it just disaapears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given below is the working snippet. Hope you will be happy to see the **solution**.

```js
var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
    menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
    menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
    menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
    showLeft = document.getElementById( 'showLeft' ),
    showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
    showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
    showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
    showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
    showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
    body = document.body;

   showLeft.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
   };
   showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRight' );
   };
   showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
   };
   showBottom.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showBottom' );
   };
   showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
   };
   showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
   };

   function disableOther( button ) {
    if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
     classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
     classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
     classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showBottom' ) {
     classie.toggle( showBottom, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
     classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
     classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
   }
```

```css
/* General styles for all menus */
.cbp-spmenu {
 background: #47a3da;
 position: fixed;
}

.cbp-spmenu h3 {
 color: #afdefa;
 font-size: 1.9em;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 background: #0d77b6;
}

.cbp-spmenu a {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:hover {
 background: #258ecd;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:active {
 background: #afdefa;
 color: #47a3da;
}

/* Orientation-dependent styles for the content of the menu */

.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
 width: 240px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.cbp-spmenu-vertical a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #258ecd;
 padding: 1em;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal h3 {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0.8em;
 border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}

/* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */

.cbp-spmenu-left {
 left: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right {
 right: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-left.cbp-spmenu-open {
 left: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right.cbp-spmenu-open {
 right: 0px;
}

/* Horizontal menu that slides from the top or bottom */

.cbp-spmenu-top {
 top: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom {
 bottom: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-top.cbp-spmenu-open {
 top: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open {
 bottom: 0px;
}

/* Push classes applied to the body */

.cbp-spmenu-push {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
 left: 240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
 left: -240px;
}

/* Transitions */

.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Example media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 55.1875em){

 .cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
  font-size: 75%;
  height: 110px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-top {
  top: -110px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-bottom {
  bottom: -110px;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-height: 26.375em){

 .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-left,
 .cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
  left: -190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-right {
  right: -190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
  left: 190px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/demoad.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/js/classie.js"></script>
<nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
   <h3>Menu</h3>
   <a href="#">Celery seakale</a>
   <a href="#">Dulse daikon</a>
   <a href="#">Zucchini garlic</a>
   <a href="#">Catsear azuki bean</a>
   <a href="#">Dandelion bunya</a>
   <a href="#">Rutabaga</a>
<img class="menu-btn" style="position: absolute; right: -48px; top: 50px;" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-48.png" id="showLeft">
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the open n close image inside your menu, and just change the default style of the menu (left) so that it shows part of the menu (the image part)

For example in http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/ 
the default style is
    .cbp-spmenu-left {
        left: -240px;
    }

if 240px is the width of the menu div, if you change it to be -200px, it will show 40 pixels to the right of your menu